# There is nothing in my $HOME/.vimrc file, is that right?

Tags: command-line, vim

I am using an Ubuntu Desktop I think Focal, version 20 and I need to add some line numbers to my vim and I ran the following command to locate my `.vimrc` file:

`vim --version`

which says my file is in `$HOME/.vimrc`, but when I run `vim $HOME/.vimrc`, there is nothing in there. is that by default or am I in the wrong place?

Comment: `~/.vimrc` is used to customize your use of `vim`. Initially, you have an uncustomized, vanilla `vim`, with none of your customizations,  so, naturally, `~/.vimrc` is empty.

Comment: @waltinator, thank you I was not aware of that. I have not used vim in a long time and much less on an Ubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 0):

> I ran the following command to locate my .vimrc file:
> `vim --version`
> which says my file is in $HOME/.vimrc

It does not say that. It says that a user vimrc file can be `$HOME/.vimrc` or, if that does not exist, `~/.vim/vimrc`. If none of these exist, the system wide configuration file `/etc/vimrc` is used.

If nothing is in there, then it means you did not put anything in there yet.